# Create new column with condition by repeat values and when have break points

Tags: r, conditional-statements, repeat, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

My data is about 40 animals (ids) with locations by telemetry, and I have already stipulated 3 areas. The first one is `AR`, where is breeding area, `AM` migration, and `AA` is feeding area. The first locations of all animals is at `AR`. But sometimes the animal is in breeding period yet (at `AR`), but can go out to `AM` few times, and then came back to `AR`. Only when the animal have only `AM` they started the migration, until arrive at feeding area `AA`. So, they start at `AR`, then start the migration `AM` and then arrive at the feeding area `AA`.

Im trying to create a new column with some conditions that I dont know yet how to do,
I have this data frame for example

```
id     area   
2304   AR
2304   AR
2304   AR
2304   AM  #this AM for example, can repeat until 20 times and then came back to AR
2304   AM
2304   AR
2304   AR
2304   AR
2304   AM
2304   AM
2304   AM
2304   AM
2304   ...
2304   AM
2304   AM
2304   AM
2304   AA
2304   AA
2304   ...
2304   AA
```

So, when have AR x times and after this have one or until 20 AM and came back have AR, I want a new column with AR.
By the moment when have AM x times and only AM, without come back to AR, I want new column with AM. Like this:

And AA its ok, AA = AA always

**I expected this:**

```
id    area    fixed_area
2304   AR      AR
2304   AR      AR
2304   AR      AR
2304   AM      AR  #this AM for example, can repeat until 20 times and then came back to AR
2304   AM      AR
2304   AR      AR
2304   AR      AR
2304   AR      AR
2304   AM      AM
2304   AM      AM
2304   AM      AM
2304   AM      AM
2304   ...     ...
2304   AM      AM
2304   AM      AM
2304   AM      AM
2304   AA      AA
2304   AA      AA
2304   ...    ...
2304   AA      AA
```

I tryed this:

but the `AA` is missing, maybe the problem is because need do this separation per animal (id)

```
> table(df$area)

   AA    AM    AR 
31460 39101 28820 

class(df$area)
[1] "character"
> idx <- with(rle(as.character(df$area)), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))
> df$fixed_area <- with(df, replace(area, idx < max(idx[area == 'AM']), 'AR'))
> table(df$fixed_area)

   AM    AR 
  145 99236 
>
```

After this I dput the data frame, but my data frame have more than 90.000 rows, so I copied just head values

```
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(DeployID = c("111868_16", "111868_16", "111868_16", 
"111868_16", "111868_16", "111868_16"), Start = structure(c(1477323868, 
1477323946, 1477324002, 1477324044, 1477324260, 1477324480), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), End = structure(c(1477323944, 1477324000, 
1477324042, 1477324170, 1477324458, 1477324542), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), What = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("Dive", "Message", "Surface"), class = "factor"), 
    Shape = structure(c(2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
    "Square", "U", "V"), class = "factor"), DepthMean = c(14.5, 
    16.5, 13, 14.5, 11, 12.5), DurationMean = c(76, 54, 40, 126, 
    198, 62), DepthMin = c(14.5, 16.5, 13, 14.5, 11, 12.5), DepthMax = c(14.5, 
    16.5, 13, 14.5, 11, 12.5), depth_range = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("shallow", "deep"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), MidTime = structure(c(1477323906, 1477323973, 
    1477324022, 1477324107, 1477324359, 1477324511), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
    2016, 2016), id = c("111868_16", "111868_16", "111868_16", 
    "111868_16", "111868_16", "111868_16"), segmentid = c("111868_16", 
    "111868_16", "111868_16", "111868_16", "111868_16", "111868_16"
    ), mu.x = c(-4446545.25191192, -4446557.10576816, -4446565.77504969, 
    -4446580.81370994, -4446625.40007808, -4446652.29459533), 
    mu.y = c(-2305423.86124176, -2305461.88537725, -2305489.69364377, 
    -2305537.93137917, -2305680.93056743, -2305767.17264774), 
    lon = c(-39.9439956132156, -39.944102098218, -39.944179975699, 
    -39.9443150702825, -39.9447155964422, -39.9449571940013), 
    lat = c(-20.3985940756941, -20.3989161274532, -20.3991516537744, 
    -20.3995602097098, -20.4007713539709, -20.4015017842338), 
    lq_closest_filt = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), dt_closest_filt = c(0.0516666666666667, 
    0.0702777777777778, 0.0838888888888889, 0.1075, 0.1775, 0.219722222222222
    ), dist_closest_filt = c(0.103680210832692, 0.141026573116106, 
    0.168339162761167, 0.215717097671267, 0.356168027785347, 
    0.440874049523752), rel.angle = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), speed = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), depth_bin = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("(0,50]", "(50,100]", "(100,150]", 
    "(150,200]", "(200,250]", "(250,300]", "(300,350]", "(350,400]", 
    "(400,450]", "(450,500]", "(500,550]", "(550,600]", "(600,650]", 
    "(650,700]"), class = "factor"), bat = structure(list(depth = c(-59L, 
    -59L, -59L, -59L, -59L, -59L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"), 
    area = c("AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Someone know how fix this? Thanks!

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you want to accomplish here:  You want a new column "fixed_area" with the levels "AA" , "AR" and "AM"  based on the already existing column "area" that has the same levels? But the difference should be, that it excluds "short trips(< 20times)" from AR to AM for each individual animal?

Comment: Yes, I want new column based on the column 'area'. Some animals are still at breeding period (`AR`), but they can go out and enter the migration area (`AM`) sometimes, but they didnt started the migration yet, so they came back to the breeding area (`AR`) again, and this movement can happen a few times. For an example, AR, AR, AR, AR, **AM**, **AM**, AR, AR, **AM**, **AM**, AR, AR this animal is on breeding period (`AR`) yet because they go out to migration area (`AM`) and then came back to breeding area (`AR`), and this movement to migration area (`AM`) can have until 20 location. Yes, per ID

Comment: The animal only starts the migration (`AM`) when have only AM, AM, AM ... AM, and when have `AA` where is the feeding area, its right, `AA` is `AA`

Comment: @user12256545 I edited my post too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might want a few rules employed to decide which rows with `AM` become `AR`.

- If the number of consecutive `AM` is < 20
- If the following destination is *not* `AA`

One approach would be to add columns related to these two rules, using `rle`. One column would have `lengths` for number of consecutive values within a repeated sequence. The other column would have the "next" area. This would be relevant to decide if the destination is back to breeding area, or onwards to a feeding area.

Finally, you can use a conditional statement and change those rows with `AM` to `AR` that meet these criteria:

- Current `area` is `AM`
- Next `area` afterwards is *not* `AA`
- The number of repeated values is less than 20

Here is the code:

```
df_rle <- rle(df$area)
df2 <- cbind(df, next_area = with(df_rle, rep(c(values[-1], NA), lengths)),
                 count = with(df_rle, rep(lengths, lengths)))
df2$area <- ifelse(with(df2, area == "AM" & next_area != "AA" & count < 20),
                   "AR", df2$area)
```